# Почему ответ "частично верный"? Как раставить знаки, чтобы ответ был верным?

Tags: пунктуация

Задание №20 к ЕГЭ на одном из сайтов. ***Почему ответ оказался "частично верным"?***

Вариант №7

***Расставьте знаки препинания: укажите все цифры, на месте которых в предложении должны стоять запятые.***

Ангелина Семеновна выяснила (1) что Вениамин уколов не делал (2) и (3) что сейчас их делать уже поздно (4) потому что (5) если собака была бешеная (6) то и он в ближайшие дни непременно должен взбеситься.

Ваш ответ: 1, 4, 6.

Частично верный ответ. (3 из 5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Почему ответ “частично верный”?**

Ответ тривиальный: по той простой причине, что "в Интернете кто-то неправ".

Ваш ответ верен.

**Как раставить знаки, чтобы ответ был верным?**

Если цель именно в том, чтобы угадать помыслы авторов этого сайта, я бы предложил поставить ещё две запятые в наименее дурацких местах.

Comment: Несколько забавно полагать, что авторы что-то там помышляли **вопреки** авторской орфографии. Просто сдуру написали. Скорее всего в ответ вкралась техническая ошибка.

Comment: И да, а какие места тут "наименее дурацкие"? Тут все три оставшихся - наиболее.))) Ну разве что перед "если" одна, а вторая?

Answer (score 0):

Ответ: 1, 4, 6.

Ангелина Семеновна выяснила, что Вениамин уколов не делал и что сейчас их делать уже поздно, потому что если собака была бешеная, то и он в ближайшие дни непременно должен взбеситься.

Comment: Вот Вы сами запятые в предложении расставили верно, а ответ написали неверный.

Comment: Цифры писал и переписывал, и вот опять. Согласен, пятёрка лишняя.

Answer (score 0):

**О термине** "частично верный ответ".

Возможно, здесь такая **логика.**

Если указать номера, где должны стоять запятые (в данном предложении это 1, 4, 6), то это полностью верный ответ.

Если назвать количество верных ответов (3 из 6), то это будет частично верный ответ (с цифрой 5 они немного ошиблись, так как всего указано шесть номеров).

Comment: 3 из 5 означает, что авторы задания принимают 3 цифры 146 как правильные, но всего предполагают 5 запятых из предложенных  6 вариантов.

Comment: Спасибо, правда, я ничего не поняла. Значит, три точные запятые указаны соответствующими номерами (1, 4, 6).  По поводу двух оставшихся  (вероятно, 2 и 5) можно сомневаться или их допускается поставить? А вот одна запятая - это точно лишняя (догадайтесь, дети,  какая). Я правильно поняла замысел составителей или нет?  С другой стороны, сомневаться-то я могу, но постановка сомнительных запятых будет ошибкой. Какой же это частично верный ответ? Что-то у них там с логикой не всё в порядке. И вывод:  бедные дети...

Comment: А кстати, Вы считаете такой термин  (частично верный) допустимым? Как его можно определить? Может быть, я просто не понимаю его смысла. Я бы частично верным считала бы такой ответ: ученик правильно расставил запятые, но неправильно объяснил причину их постановки.

Comment: Термин "частично верный"  допустим только для ответов на  задания 8 (максимально можно получить 5 баллов, если одна ошибка - 4, если 2 ошибки - 3 балла и т.п.), 26 (максимальный балл 4) и 16 (можно получить 2 балла). Все остальные задания весят 1 балл. В 2019 году ЕГЭ не предполагает объяснения причин постановки или непостановки запятых в задании 20 и других заданиях, связанных с пунктуацией.

Comment: Эта информация понятна: частично верный - это ответ с некоторым количеством ошибок. А для чего вообще нужен этот термин? В зачет все равно пойдет определенное количество баллов. А что означают цифры? Если правильно поставить три запятые, то 5 баллов, потом 4 балла, потом 3 балла, а за шесть запятых 0 баллов, ответ считается неверным?

Answer (score 0):

Трудно объяснить, что тут "частично".
Полагаю, что авторы *неподумавши* решили, что в (6) тоже должна быть запятая. Логика тут, как понимаете, есть, хотя она и противоречит современным правилам. Но у Алексина именно так, никаких "авторских" знаков.

> Она выяснила, что Веник уколов не делал и что сейчас их делать уже
>   поздно, потому что если собака была бешеная, так и Веник в ближайшие
>   дни непременно должен взбеситься.
>   (Алексин, "Саша и Шура").

*Я с детства помню эту книгу и эпизод с неуколотым Веником, пройти мимо не мог, решил на всякий пожарный посмотреть, как там у автора. Жаль, у меня не сохранилось то, моё детское издание.*

А вообще надо давать URL сайта, если вы уж решили разбираться с источником.